# How do I set the callout view’s background color when using the Mapbox iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mapbox

I'm building a map application with the Mapbox SDK. Here is how I present an annotation on the map and auto-show the title popup:

```
[myAnnotation setCoordinate:touchMapCoordinate];
myAnnotation.title = @"This Is A Title";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:myAnnotation animated:YES];
```

Currently, the title pops up with a standard white background. However, I'd like the title to have a black background, as I use the light map and want the pop up to stand out a bit more. How could I do this?

Comment: Did you check the custom marker documentation? https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/marker-image/

Comment: @UlyssesR yes, I'm able to add a custom marker image. however i'm not sure how to change the background of the "Leaning Tower of Pisa" text

Comment: Hum, as far as I could look, seems not possible to change the color, just check the attributes of the MGLPointAnnotation, https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.0.0/Classes/MGLPointAnnotation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Mapbox iOS SDK v3.2.0, the default callout view isn’t exposed and you’re not able to change its appearance beyond [adding accessory views and title text](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/callout-delegate/).

Instead, you should provide a custom callout view that conforms to the [MGLCalloutView](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.1.2/Protocols/MGLCalloutView.html) protocol, then display it with your map using the MGLMapViewDelegate method [-mapView:calloutForAnnotation:](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.1.2/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapView:calloutViewForAnnotation:).

See [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/custom-callout/) for a working implementation in both Objective-C and Swift. The default callout view uses [SMCalloutView](https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview) and you could relatively easily adapt this example to also use it.

Comment: crazy. I spent an entire night searching the docs and somehow didn't come across this. thank you!

Comment: The custom callout example is brand new (this week) and only became possible with v3.1. :D

Comment: @friedbunny I took a shot at a custom callout view and had a hard time replicating the default callout just so I could change the background color and the font. Is it possible for us to see how Mapbox constructed the default callout?

Comment: @sconewolf the default callout is https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview.